# C++ <complex> and <complex.h> in the same file

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a large code base that uses the c++ `<complex>` header and many `std::complex<double>` objects.  But now I also want to use a couple other libraries ([`fftw`](http://www.fftw.org/) and [`spinsfast`](http://astrophysics.physics.fsu.edu/~huffenbe/research/spinsfast/index.html)) that use `<complex.h>`.  Unfortunately, mixing these two types of complex seems to be incompatible with gcc 4.6.1 (presumably among others).

Here's a minimal working example showing the error:

```
// This is what I do for my various complex objects
#include <complex>

// This is one of many things FFTW/spinsfast essentially do
extern "C" {
  #include <complex.h>
}

int main() {
  std::complex<double>(1.0,2.0);
  return 0;
}
```

And when I compile:

```
> g++ test.cpp -o test
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:7:8: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘_Complex’
test.cpp:7:8: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘_Complex’
```

Evidently, gcc is translating `std::complex<double>` into `_Complex`, which somehow is also undefined.  [This works fine on my macbook, which uses Apple LLVM version 5.1; this compiler error is happening on a cluster that I need to support.]

I can't even figure out where this is coming from; none of the include files in my gcc installation have "_Complex" -- though they do have "_ComplexT".  How do I debug this kind of thing?

Or more helpfully, how do I solve this compiler error in a way that will work for more than just a small slice of `gcc`s?

Comment: Have you tried to include both `<complex>` and `<ccomplex>` instead of `<complex.h>`?

Comment: It seems like `complex.h` defines `complex` being `_Complex` according to http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/complex.h.html

Comment: No problem here with gcc 4.8.2.  Also, you generally don't need the `extern "C"{}` wrapper around standard library headers because the headers are usually written to work under either C or C++, but check your particular headers to be sure.

Comment: `_Complex` is a keyword in C, part of types such as `float _Complex` etc.

Comment: g++ 4.8.1 doesn't give an error. g++ 4.7.3 shows the same error you quoted. It seems like since g++ 4.8 they do not `#define complex _Complex` anymore when `<complex>` is also included (they still do if you don't include it)

Comment: @Edward I added the `extern` just because it's actually what I do to include `fftw3.h` and `spinsfast.h`.  But I've tried without it, and get the same result.

Comment: Just compared `<complex>` of g++ 4.7.3 vs 4.8.1: They added `#undef complex` with the comment `// Get rid of a macro possibly defined in <complex.h>` I guess this explains it ;)

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54112

Comment: Ah, that explains it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C, `_Complex` is a keyword used to declare complex numbers: `float _Complex`. However, they `#define complex _Complex` so you can write `float complex` which looks nicer.

Of course, you get in trouble when using the name `complex` in a context other than where you want `_Complex`, such as `std::complex`, which then expands to `std::_Complex`.

So if you use `<complex>` in C++, you should get rid of this macro:

```
#include <complex.h>
#undef complex
```

That's actually what g++ does since 4.8 to support both `<complex>` and `<complex.h>` in the same translation unit.

Note that when enabling C++11, you won't get the error either.

Comment: Hm.  That works in my MWE, alright, but in my real code I get `error: no match for call to ‘(std::complex<double>) (double, double)’`.  Maybe my MWE was too M...

Comment: Well, by reordering my includes and removing any variable named `I`, this all seems to work now...  Thanks!

Comment: The issue with `I` is related to http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59087 and as you guessed it is best to simply avoid I in your code.

Comment: Ah, and explained again!  Thanks very much.  :)