# c++ and <complex.h> with <complex> in separate files

Tags: c++, c, complex-numbers

#### Notes:

I am compiling on OSX using Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)

Specifically, I am trying to compile a monolithic source from LibIIR, a filter library maintained [here](http://www.lwithers.me.uk/usr/src/libiir/) by Laurence Withers.

I've already looked at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414270/c-complex-and-complex-h-in-the-same-file) about using both `<complex>` and `<complex.h>` in the *same file*.

---

#### Setup:

I have a file `iir.h` like so:

```
#include <complex.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

...
```

I have C++ source and header files `libiir++.cpp` and `iir++.h` like so:

```
/*** libiir++.cpp ***/
// we need to include "iir.h" first, as it pulls in <complex.h>, which we need
// to take effect before "iir++.h" pulls in <complex>
#include "iir.h"

// now remove the preprocessor definition of complex to _Complex, which is fine
// for the C header but not good for the C++ header
#undef complex

#include "iir++.h"

namespace IIR {

...
```

-

```
/*** iir++.h ***/
#include <complex>

namespace IIR {

...
```

#### Problem:

clang gives me the following error when compiling:

```
./iir.h:570:15: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
double complex iir_response_c(const struct iir_coeff_t* coeff, double freq);
              ^
              ;
```

Evidently, the new `<complex>` import is not happening--or `#undef complex` is happening again--but I don't see how. Any advice on what might be going wrong, or what to check?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<complex.h>` is a C header and it is not compatible with C++.

C++ defines C library compatibility through headers named in the pattern `<c***>`. So, the C++ counterpart to `<complex.h>` is named `<ccomplex>`. Here's what the C++ standard has to say about that:

> #### Header `<ccomplex>`
>
> The header behaves as if it simply includes the header `<complex>`.

If you attempt to use the C complex number library, you just get the C++ one instead.

Bottom line: you simply cannot run C complex math through a C++ compiler. At best, you can use the preprocessor to generate equivalent programs depending on `__cplusplus`.

For example,

```
#if __cplusplus
#   include <complex>
    typedef std::complex< double > cdouble;
#else
#   include <complex.h>
    typedef double complex cdouble;
#endif
```

Note, `std::complex< double >` and `double complex` are layout-compatible per C++14 [complex.numbers] §26.4/4 and C11 §6.2.5/13. The intent seems to be that you can use `cdouble` for cross-language function prototypes, although strictly speaking it depends on the ABI.

---

Incidentally, the C++ standard does define what happens when you `#include <complex.h>`, but it doesn't make any sense:

> Every C header, each of which has a name of the form `name.h`, behaves as if each name placed in the standard library namespace by the corresponding *`cname`* header is placed within the global namespace scope. It is unspecified whether these names are first declared or defined within namespace scope (3.3.6) of the namespace `std` and are then injected into the global namespace scope by explicit *using-declarations* (7.3.3).

So, `#include <complex.h>` should give you a global `::complex<T>`. This is a defect in the standard.

Comment: S should I then do `#ifdef __cplusplus #include <ccomplex> #else #include <complex.h> #endif` inside the `.h` file instead of always including `<complex.h>`?

Comment: Also, this successfully compiled when not using llvm and clang--I did this using g++/gcc version 4.8.2.

Comment: @B-Brock Updated with an example of that.

Comment: The "defect in the standard" has been corrected for C++17; the quoted block now begins "Every **other** C header..." with a previous paragraph excluding complex.h and tgmath.h.   Also, `complex.h` and `ccomplex` are deprecated.