# identifier "creal" is undefined - seen on Mac but not on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, macos, complextype

## Question

Is the following code wrong or is there an issue with the headers on Mac?  The error does not appear on Linux, which leads me to conclude it is not incorrect code, although successful compilation on Linux is not a particularly rigorous test for ISO compliance.

## Source Code (MCVE)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>

void foo(const double *A, int *size){
   for(int i=0;i < size[0]; ++i){
      for(int j=0;j < size[1]; ++j){
         printf("(%.2e,%.2e) ", creal(A[i + j * size[0]]), cimag(A[i + j * size[0]]));
      }
   }
}
```

## Mac

### System Info

```
$ uname -a
Darwin redacted 15.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.4.0: Fri Feb 26 22:08:05 PST 2016; root:xnu-3248.40.184~3/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

### Intel compiler

```
$ icpc -v
icpc version 16.0.2 (gcc version 4.9.0 compatibility)
$ icpc -c ttc-creal.cpp 
ttc-creal.cpp(7): error: identifier "creal" is undefined
           printf("(%.2e,%.2e) ", creal(A[i + j * size[0]]), cimag(A[i + j * size[0]]));
                                  ^

ttc-creal.cpp(7): error: identifier "cimag" is undefined
           printf("(%.2e,%.2e) ", creal(A[i + j * size[0]]), cimag(A[i + j * size[0]]));
                                                             ^

compilation aborted for ttc-creal.cpp (code 2)
```

### LLVM compiler

```
$ clang++ -v
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
$ clang++ -c ttc-creal.cpp 
ttc-creal.cpp:7:33: error: use of undeclared identifier 'creal'
         printf("(%.2e,%.2e) ", creal(A[i + j * size[0]]), cimag(A[i + j * size[0]]));
                                ^
ttc-creal.cpp:7:60: error: use of undeclared identifier 'cimag'
         printf("(%.2e,%.2e) ", creal(A[i + j * size[0]]), cimag(A[i + j * size[0]]));
                                                           ^
2 errors generated.
```

## Linux

### System Info

```
$ uname -a
Linux redacted 2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.centos.plus.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Feb 10 18:09:24 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

### GNU compiler

```
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/gcc/5.3.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: /home/redacted/Work/GCC/gcc-5.3.0/configure --prefix=/opt/gcc/5.3.0 --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --with-tune=native --enable-bootstrap --enable-lto --with-mpfr --with-isl --with-gmp --with-mpc --with-cloog --enable-gold --enable-ld --disable-multilib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.3.0 (GCC) 
$ g++ -c ttc-creal.cpp
<no error>
```

### Intel compiler

```
$ icpc -v
icpc version 17.0.0 Beta (gcc version 5.3.0 compatibility)
$ icpc -c ttc-creal.cpp
<no error>
```

### LLVM compiler

```
$ clang++ -v
clang version 3.4.2 (tags/RELEASE_34/dot2-final)
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7
$ clang++ -c ttc-creal.cpp 
<no error>
```

## Investigation

I have read through all of the relevant `complex.h`, `ccomplex` and `complex` headers on my Mac, but cannot see an obvious reason for this issue.

Comment: Your MCVE could be even more minimal. After the 2 #includes, you only need a main() with 1 line: `printf("%lf", creal(3.5));`. That aside, I've tried some online compilers. According to http://melpon.org/wandbox/ it works from gcc 4.8.1, but no version of Clang compiles it. Even MSVC gives an error (tried at http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/ and at http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual). But I think the problem is in the libraries, not in the compiler itself. Not sure how much this can help, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just Clang's read of the C++ standard - see [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31800404/1374437) - which to me appears to be the correct one. Basically, you are not supposed to use the C99 complex type and the associated functions in C++ and should use `std::complex<T>` instead. Both complex types should be layout-compatible and you should be able to pass complex data between C and C++ code.

`g++`'s `complex.h` includes both `<ccomplex>` (in C++11 mode) and the C `<complex.h>` and therefore the code compiles with GCC (from Homebrew in my case). I don't have the Intel compiler for OS X, but you could check what it does with `icpc -E ttc-creal.cpp | grep complex` and observe the sequence of include file expansions.

Clang:

```
$ clang++ -E ttc-creal.cpp | grep "^# 1 " | grep complex
# 1 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/complex.h" 1 3
# 1 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ccomplex" 1 3
# 1 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/complex" 1 3
```

GCC:

```
$ g++-5 -E ttc-creal.cpp | grep "^# 1 " | grep complex
# 1 "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.3.0/include/c++/5.3.0/complex.h" 1 3
# 1 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/complex.h" 1 3 4

$ g++-5 -std=c++11 -E ttc-creal.cpp | grep "^# 1 " | grep complex
# 1 "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.3.0/include/c++/5.3.0/complex.h" 1 3
# 1 "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.3.0/include/c++/5.3.0/ccomplex" 1 3
# 1 "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.3.0/include/c++/5.3.0/complex" 1 3
# 1 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/complex.h" 1 3 4
```

You can force Clang to include `<path to SDK>/usr/include/complex.h` by e.g.:

```c
#include "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/complex.h"
```

and your MCVE will compile, but doing so is probably a very Bad Idea (tm).

By the way, the same behaviour is observed on FreeBSD 10.2-RELEASE with Clang 3.4.1 (error) and GCC 4.8.5 (success).

*All credit goes to Potatoswatter - the author of the the answer referenced at the top.*

Comment: Thanks.  Adding this to the list of reasons I hate C++, but unfortunately, I did not write the code in question, so it's not in my control to change it.