# Call C++ function with complex parameters and complex return type out of C code

Tags: c++, c, macos

I have a C++ mathematical library and writing a project in Rust. Since it is not possible to call C++ directly from Rust, but to call C is possible, I decided to write a standard wrapper from C++ into C.

Everything is working more or less as expected except of functions which have complex parameters, where the imaginary part is lost for some reason. Below I provide mwe.

**export_c++.h**

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <complex>
std::complex<double> foo(const std::complex<double> a);
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include <complex.h>

double _Complex c_foo(const double _Complex a);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

**export_c++.cc**

```
#include "export_c++.h"

#include <iostream>

std::complex<double> foo(const std::complex<double> a){
    return a;
}

double _Complex c_foo(const double _Complex a){
    std::complex<double> b{a};
    double _Complex res{b.real(), b.imag()};

    return res; 
}
```

now we compile this as

```
g++ -c -std=gnu++11 -o export_c++.o export_c++.cc
```

and assemble into library

```
ar rcs libexport_c++.a export_c++.o
```

and we will use it in **main.c**

```
#include "export_c++.h"

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double complex a = 1. + I * 1.;
    double complex b = c_foo(a);
    printf("a = %f + I %f\n", creal(a), cimag(a));
    printf("b = %f + I %f\n", creal(b), cimag(b));
    return 0;
}
```

Compile main.c

```
gcc -o main -L. -lexport_c++ main.c
```

and run

```
./main
```

which yields

```
a = 1.000000 + I 1.000000
b = 1.000000 + I 0.000000
```

I use macOS and compile with

```
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
```

Also these two questions are somewhat relevant to the question
[identifier "creal" is undefined - seen on Mac but not on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36747506/identifier-creal-is-undefined-seen-on-mac-but-not-on-linux) and 
[c++ and <complex.h> with <complex> in separate files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31800065/c-and-complex-h-with-complex-in-separate-files/31800404#31800404)

Of course, as a workaround I can split the complex parameters into two `double` ones, since in any case I would call the code out of rust.

By the way, compilation with gcc 7.1.0

```
g++-7 -c -std=gnu++11 -o export_c++.o export_c++.cc
ar rcs libexport_c++.a export_c++.o
gcc-7 -o main -L. -lexport_c++ -lstdc++ main.c
```

produces expected result

```
a = 1.000000 + I 1.000000
b = 1.000000 + I 1.000000
```

Comment: IIRC, you can't use `_Complex` from within C++; they are C only. [One of the answers to the question you linked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31800404/1896169) says so.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more source file:

**export_c++.h**

```
//
// c and c++
//
struct complex_proxy
{
    double real;
    double imaginary;
};

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

struct complex_proxy proxy_foo(struct complex_proxy a);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

//
// c++ only
//
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <complex>

std::complex<double> foo(const std::complex<double> a);

#else

#include <complex.h>

double _Complex c_foo(const double _Complex a);

#endif
```

**export_c++.cpp**

```
#include "export_c++.h"

std::complex<double> foo(const std::complex<double> a){
    return a;
}


struct complex_proxy proxy_foo(struct complex_proxy a)
{
    auto result = foo({a.real, a.imaginary});
    return { result.real(), result.imag() };
}
```

**export_c++.c**

```
#include "export_c++.h"

double _Complex c_foo(const double _Complex a)
{

    struct complex_proxy a_proxy = { creal(a), cimag(a) };
    struct complex_proxy result = proxy_foo(a_proxy);
    return result.real + result.imaginary * I;
}
```

Comment: `struct complex_proxy` (instead of `complex_proxy`) as type in a C++ (source) file? Just for symmetry with the header, I guess?

Comment: @DanielJour I wrote the header first, then cut/paste into the cpp file. But you're right, it does provide a clue that this is an implementation of a C function.

Comment: Thanks. It works. However, it would be also nice to understand why this problems with complex numbers are happening in clang and not in gcc. Is it some undocumented feature of gcc?

Comment: @tupos it's simple. _Complex is part of c, not part of c++. gcc ignores this and provides _Complex as an extension in c++, clang does not. Both are correct.