# What does a typedef with three arguments mean?

Tags: c++, macros, g++, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to compile code that includes the following header file:

```
#ifndef FFT_H
#define FFT_H

#include<cmath>
#include<complex.h>
#include<vector>

#define Vec(a, b) std::vector<__typeof(*(a))> ((a), (a)+(b))

typedef double complex complex_t; // this is my trouble line!
typedef double real_t;

#endif
```

My compiler is tripping up over `typedef double complex complex_t;`

This makes sense to me because most typedefs include only two arguments: the type, and the alias name.

This published code is from a [reputable source](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/netmit/sFFT/code.html) so I assume I'm doing something wrong on my end. However, I'm confused as to why a typedef would ever use 3 arguments.

Comment: `typedef unsigned long long int ull;` — five arguments?  (Dubious nomenclature — they aren't really arguments — but that's a separate topic.)

Comment: Your problem is that you are including a C header, `<complex.h>`, in what is presumably a C++ compilation.  C++ has its own header, `<complex>`, that defines the complex types you should be using in C++.  You should not attempt to use the C types.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Last I checked, that was technically invalid C++, though every compiler supports it anyway

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I agree with you. However, <complex> does not seem to seem to contain the proper typedef definition.

Comment: I've not got a C++ standard readily accessible on this machine — I can't check what `<ccomplex>` provides to a C++ program without hacking around sites I don't normally visit.  But I expect `<ccomplex>` provides what it is supposed to provide; it just probably doesn't provide what you think it should provide.  I think you'll find there's an expectation mismatch between what the standard says and what you'd like it to say, or maybe what the author of the code thinks it should say since you say it isn't your code.

Comment: @MooingDuck does your comment refer to Jonathan's first comment or his second comment?

Comment: @M.M. First comment. C++ spec says the first parameter to a `typedef` is a identifier or simple-template-id, and `unsigned long long int`, is (awkwardly) neither of these making it technically illegal C++.

Comment: Note that CPPReference.com says [`<ccomplex>` is deprecated in C++17 and removed in C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/ccomplex).  The [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/libstdc++/manual/manual/using_headers.html) says much the same and lists some other headers that are deprecated and/or removed.

Comment: @MooingDuck any valid variable or function declaration (without initializer) can have `typedef` prepended to it. The spec does not say what you claim. The specification of declaration syntax includes `typedef` amongst the decl-specifiers (of which there can be any number), there is no special syntax for typedefs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c++ and <complex.h> with <complex> in separate files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31800065/c-and-complex-h-with-complex-in-separate-files)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think that answers it. I'm using g++ per the distributors makefile and I think it should be compiled as C99 but is being compiled as C++...

Comment: is no one going to address the `Vec` macro? Oookey.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, most typedefs contain the alias name and the underlying type, but there's *no* requirement that the type be a single token:

```
typedef unsigned long long int ULLI;
//      \____________________/
//  Many tokens for underlying type
```

So whatever your code works under appears to have already a `double complex` type.

This type is *actually* part of the C standard, held in `<complex.h>` but the equivalent C++ `<ccomplex>/<complex.h>` header has now been replaced with `<complex>`, more suited to C++, so it would be more proper to include that and use the `complex<double>` type.

I believe, as of C++17, `<ccomplex>/<complex.h>` stopped holding any legacy C stuff and just started including other non-legacy headers from the C++ standard library.

And then, in C++20, they ditched it altogether. From (slightly paraphrased) `C++20 [diff.cpp17.library]`, which details the differences:

> Change: Remove vacuous C++ header files.
>
> Rationale: Empty headers implied a false requirement to achieve C compatibility with the C++ headers.
>
> Effect on original feature: A valid C++ 2017 program that performs a `#include` of `<ccomplex>` (amongst others) may fail to compile. To retain the same behavior, a `#include` of `<ccomplex>` can be replaced by a `#include` of `<complex>`.

Comment: So you're saying there should exist a "typedef double complex" somewhere before the "typedef double complex complex_t"? Looking at my code, I could think it would be in either <cmath> or <complex.h>. The compile should fail though if these aren't found?

Comment: @HTNW: I was thinking more of a C/C++ distinction but you're right, my choice of terms was messy. Will fix.

Answer (score 3):

`complex` is not a keyword in C++, and `double complex` is not a type . You are mixing up C++ with another language .

Instead you can use `std::complex<double>`, with or without a typedef.

Answer (score 1):

It's hacky but change <complex.h> to "/usr/include/complex.h" which will force the author intended include.  Then it should build. At least it worked for me with fedora 33 and g++ version:

```
> g++ --version 
g++ (GCC) 10.2.1 20201125 (Red Hat 10.2.1-9) Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software 
Foundation, Inc. This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR 
PURPOSE.
```