# C++11 complex<float>* to C float complex*

Tags: c++, c

I have an array of complex floats that I'm working with in C++11:

```
std::complex<float> *cx;
```

I am trying to use an older library which takes in C style complex floats:

```
float complex *cx;
```

When I try this:

```
std::complex<float> *cpp = new std::complex<float>[100];
complex float *c = reinterpret_cast<complex float*>(cpp);
c_process(c); // c_process(complex float *c)    [ c library function ]
```

I get:

```
error: expected ';' before 'float'   
complex float *c = reinterpret_cast<complex float*>(cpp);
        ^
```

The problem is that the C library's headers contains `#include <complex.h>`, and I have `#include <complex>` in my C++11 code which uses std::complex.

`class complex` from `<complex>` and `#define complex _Complex` from `<complex.h>` seem to be clashing on the word `complex`.

**One Solution:**
**This solution only works if you can modify the other library's headers.**

Since the powers at be closed this question (although I think it's a pretty good), here's what I did:

Since `<complex.h>` has a `#define complex _Complex` and `<complex>` contains a `class complex`, there is some conflict when including both headers.

I had to change all `float complex*` to `float _Complex*` everywhere in my code and other library's header files. This removed the clash on the word `complex` from the cstyle <complex.h>'s define and c++ style's class complex without changing what the code does.

Comment: "*I've tried everything*"—then it should be pretty easy to show us what you've tried.

Comment: The rules for this website clearly specify that we're not a homework website. You're expected to show us, in a [mcve], what you've already tried to do to solve your problem. Posting the definitions for the two types you're working with doesn't satisfy that requirement. Additionally, your question is still unclear: what does "move between them" mean in this context? What's stopping you from just transforming the `std::complex<float>` array into a `_Complex` array, using elementary functions?

Comment: [I punched your code into an online compiler](https://godbolt.org/g/WKx6kF), and got a different error message, related to the `complex` keyword not mapping to a valid type. Swapping `complex` with `_Complex` eliminated the compile errors. I don't know which compiler you're using, but your compiler doesn't appear to alias `_Complex` to `complex` like the documentation suggests is possible.

Comment: You don't have to modify the header of the other library. You just have to do two things: 1. add a `#undef complex` right after you have included said library (maybe wrapped in `#ifdef`/`#endif`) 2. Do as you said, replace `complex float` with `_Complex float` in your own c++ code.

Answer (score 3):

This incompatibility is syntax only, both languages guarantee that their complex types have the same layout as a `float[2]` (or `double[2]` etc). So you could mediate between the two on having a macro `cfloat` that is defined according to the language in which it is expanded. Something along the lines of

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
typedef std::complex<float> cfloat;
#else
typedef float _Complex cfloat;
#endif
```

And then use this `cfloat` in all your function prototypes.

Comment: @Xirema C++ has made a specific exemption for `std::complex` for binary compatibility with C.

Comment: @NathanOliver Noted. The answer should probably have a reference added to the relevant text to verify that: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex

Comment: What's this `cfloat`? I tried to search the Internet for it, but failed. Is there anything more convenient than simple casting?

Answer (score 3):

It may be quite easy. `std::complex` defines the storage order of complex objects and provides ways to access the real and imaginary parts of arrays of complex objects. If the order is the same as in your older library you may be in luck

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex

> For any object `z` of type `complex<T>`, `reinterpret_cast<T(&)[2]>(z)[0]` is the real part of `z` and `reinterpret_cast<T(&)[2]>(z)[1]` is the imaginary part of `z`

and

> For any pointer to an element of an array of `complex<T>` named `p` and any valid array index `i`, `reinterpret_cast<T*>(p)[2*i]` is the real part of the complex number `p[i]`, and `reinterpret_cast<T*>(p)[2*i + 1]` is the imaginary part of the complex number `p[i]`

Thus you can refer to a C99 compatible `float _Complex *cx` simply.

> `std::complex *cx1 = reinterpret_cast*> cx;

Due to conflicts when including both `complex` and `complex.h` one approach is to pull out the basic declarations from the C header and include it in a "C" extern statement along with the used C function declarations like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

extern "C" {
    // this is commented out because it is also declared in the c++ complex header
    //typedef struct _C_float_complex
    //{ /* float complex */
    //    float _Val[2];
    //} _C_float_complex;
    typedef _C_float_complex _Fcomplex;
void double_my_reals(_Fcomplex *pcx, int len);
}


int main()
{
    std::complex<float> cf[5]{ 1,2,3,4,5 };
    for (auto x:cf)
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    double_my_reals(reinterpret_cast<_Fcomplex*>(cf), 5);
    for (auto x:cf)
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

This code is specific to Visual Studio C and C++. VSC is not compatible with C99 but the data structures are the same so you will need to pull out the specific declaration for a complex float in whatever C compiler is being used.

And this would be an example of the called "C" code for VC.

```
#include <complex.h>

void double_my_reals(_Fcomplex *pcx, int len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        pcx[i]._Val[0] *= 2.0f;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this. Please see my edits. There's something up with my headers clashing because I get some syntax errors within the library I am using. The libraries header forces me to include <complex.h> and I have to include <complex> in my C++11 code. I think the problem is that I have to have both.

Comment: In your original post you said your older C library used `_Complex` which is how C works and now you have changed it to `complex` which will clash as well as undefined. Hard to help without a more complete example.

Comment: Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414270/c-complex-and-complex-h-in-the-same-file   It goes into the necessary machinations to use <complex.h> and <complex> in the same translation unit. In particular the clash between `complex` and a macro defined in `<complex.h>`

Comment: doug, thanks for the link. That provided _some_ clarity. The problem is the functions in the header file for the library I am using. They all use "float complex*"  so "#undef complex" causes compilation errors for those function.