# Do _Complex types in C99 behave like std::complex<> in C++?

Tags: c++, multilingual, complex-numbers, c11, complextype

I've recently noticed the existence of [types for complex values](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types#Complex_floating_types) in C99  (after noticing their construction macros as a feature of C11).

Since this is C, these are built-in types, not structs with overloaded operators etc. But - is it or is it not the case that I can treat them as though they were based on C++'s `std::complex` template?  i..e. is `float _Complex` effectively the same as `std::complex<float>` and `double _Complex` the same as `std::complex<double>`?

Note: Of course they have exactly the same behavior, since C++ has features which C doesn't, but think of it as though we restrict ourselves to the "C subset" except for these two types.

If they are *not* effectively the same - please explain how they differ.

Comment: This answer might be of interest to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50955093/c11-complexfloat-to-c-float-complex

Answer (score 5):

[`std::complex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) is different from `_Complex` mainly in its interface.

To get real part of `std::complex` you use [`constexpr T real() const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/real) member function, the same for `_Complex` types requires [`creal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/complex/creal) macro.

So they are *not* the same type and it will be hard to pretend they are, but they do have the same internal layout.

C++17 29.5.4 states:

> If `z` is an lvalue expression of type cv complex then:
>
> - the expression `reinterpret_cast<cv T(&)[2]>(z)` shall be well-formed,
> - `reinterpret_cast<cv T(&)[2]>(z)[0]` shall designate the real part of `z`, and
> - `reinterpret_cast<cv T(&)[2]>(z)[1]` shall designate the imaginary part of `z`.
>
> Moreover, if `a` is an expression of type `cv complex<T>*` and the expression `a[i]` is well-defined for an integer expression `i`, then:
>
> - `reinterpret_cast<cv T*>(a)[2*i]` shall designate the real part of `a[i]`, and
> - `reinterpret_cast<cv T*>(a)[2*i + 1]` shall designate the imaginary part of `a[i]`.

And C18 6.2.5.13 states:

> Each complex type has the same representation and alignment
>   requirements as an array type containing exactly two elements of the
>   corresponding real type; the first element is equal to the real part,
>   and the second element to the imaginary part, of the complex number.

Which means you can use `std::complex<T>` and `_Complex T` to write interoperable code for C and C++.

Note: `_Complex` was introduced in C99.

Comment: If I run `creal` on an std::complex, won't I get the same thing as for a _Complex then?

Comment: There is no `creal` is C++, but there is global `std::real` for that. Would be hard to pretent they are the same type. Atomics are in similar situation - almost the same, but not exactly.

Comment: What might be the reason why C++ doesn't have a built in complex type the way C does?

Comment: @Ayxan: 1. C++ standardized in 1998, when the C standard was C89, and kept great compatibility with that. 2. The standard diverged with C99 and it did not make sense for C++ to follow C's path. 3. C++ doesn't need such a built-in type.